# Measuring python coverage at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-coverage, coverage.py

Is it possible to measure python code coverage at runtime and view the results as they are generated? I tried using [coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.4.1/) but couldn't find an option that would help. My initial experiments show that the `.coverage` file isn't saved to until the end of the programs execution, meaning we can't view the results using 'coverage html' or 'coverage report'.

Comment: Do you not have a way to end your program cleanly?

Comment: @NedBatchelder my use case is more for if I have a continuously running program like a web server and I wanted to see where my code hasn't been touched over a longer period of time

Comment: Maybe adding a way to end the server will be easier than using the coverage API in the code.

Comment: @NedBatchelder perhaps during development that would be fine. I was thinking of a production environment where interrupting the server is probably not a good idea. Perhaps I'll make a PR into coverage at some point to add this.

Comment: If you want to take it on, drop me an email so we can discuss the design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 4.4, you can call `coverage.save()` and continue running. This means you have to use the coverage.py API inside your program rather than just using the command-line interface.